# How to get sorted list inside a dictionary with json.dumps()

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have the following problem: having a python dictionary like the following:

```
{"qqq": [{"bbb": "111"}, {"aaa": "333"}], "zzz": {"bbb": [5, 2, 1, 9]}}
```

I would like to obtain an ordered json object such as:

```
'{"qqq": [{"aaa": "333"}, {"bbb": "111"}], "zzz": {"bbb": [1, 2, 5, 9]}}'
```

At the moment I use the following:

```
class ListEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, list):
            return sorted(o)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

print json.dumps(c, sort_keys=True, cls=ListEncoder)
```

But the two list inside my object are not sorted, and I get:

```
'{"qqq": [{"bbb": "111"}, {"aaa": "333"}], "zzz": {"bbb": [5, 2, 1, 9]}}'
```

probably because the custom JSONEncoder skips a type that already knows how to manage (list).

#### UPDATE

Martijn solution below works perfectly for the example above, but unfortunately I have to manage more complicated dictionaries, with a bigger depth: for example the following two

```
a = {
    'aaa': 'aaa',
    'op': 'ccc',
    'oppa': {
        'ggg': [{'fff': 'ev'}],
        'flt': {
            'nnn': [
                {
                'mmm': [{'a_b_d': [6]},{'a_b_c': [6,7]}]
                },
                {
                    'iii': [3, 2, 4, 5]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    'rrr': {},
    'ttt': ['aaa-bbb-ccc']
}
b = {
    'aaa': 'aaa',
    'op': 'ccc',
    'oppa': {
        'ggg': [{'fff': 'ev'}],
        'flt': {
            'nnn': [
                {
                    'iii': [2, 3, 4, 5]
                },
                {
                'mmm': [{'a_b_c': [6,7]},{'a_b_d': [6]}]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    'rrr': {},
    'ttt': ['aaa-bbb-ccc']
}
```

They would be the same if the lists inside the same would be sorted.
But they aren't with the class above, and I get 2 different json strings:

```
{"aaa": "aaa", "op": "ccc", "oppa": {"flt": {"nnn": [{"iii": [3, 2, 4, 1]}, {"mmm": [{"a_b_d": [6]}, {"a_b_c": [6, 7]}]}]}, "ggg": [{"fff": "ev"}]}, "rrr": {}, "ttt": ["aaa-bbb-ccc"]}
{"aaa": "aaa", "op": "ccc", "oppa": {"flt": {"nnn": [{"iii": [2, 3, 4, 5]}, {"mmm": [{"a_b_c": [6, 7]}, {"a_b_d": [6]}]}]}, "ggg": [{"fff": "ev"}]}, "rrr": {}, "ttt": ["aaa-bbb-ccc"]}
```

Any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`default` isn't called for lists; that method is only for types the encoder doesn't know how to handle. Override the `encode` method instead:

```
class SortedListEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj):
        def sort_lists(item):
            if isinstance(item, list):
                return sorted(sort_lists(i) for i in item)
            elif isinstance(item, dict):
                return {k: sort_lists(v) for k, v in item.items()}
            else:
                return item
        return super(SortedListEncoder, self).encode(sort_lists(obj))
```

This essentially just sorts all lists (recursively) before encoding; this could have been done before passing it to `json.dumps()` but this way it is part of the responsibility of the encoder, just like sorting the keys is.

Demo:

```
>>> json.dumps(c, sort_keys=True, cls=SortedListEncoder)
'{"qqq": [{"aaa": "333"}, {"bbb": "111"}], "zzz": {"bbb": [1, 2, 5, 9]}}'
>>> json.dumps(a, sort_keys=True, cls=SortedListEncoder)
'{"aaa": "aaa", "op": "ccc", "oppa": {"flt": {"nnn": [{"iii": [2, 3, 4, 5]}, {"mmm": [{"a_b_c": [6, 7]}, {"a_b_d": [6]}]}]}, "ggg": [{"fff": "ev"}]}, "rrr": {}, "ttt": ["aaa-bbb-ccc"]}'
>>> json.dumps(b, sort_keys=True, cls=SortedListEncoder)
'{"aaa": "aaa", "op": "ccc", "oppa": {"flt": {"nnn": [{"iii": [2, 3, 4, 5]}, {"mmm": [{"a_b_c": [6, 7]}, {"a_b_d": [6]}]}]}, "ggg": [{"fff": "ev"}]}, "rrr": {}, "ttt": ["aaa-bbb-ccc"]}'
```

Comment: From a style perspective, sorting lists should really be done outside of the encoder. As a data structure, lists are ordered. Dictionary keys are generally returned in an arbitrary order, and `sort_keys` simply returns them in a particular order without changing the underlying data. Perhaps a better option here would be to store the lists as sets and write an encoder for Set.

Answer (score 0):

The updated question should probably have been a new question but my solution for the update was to extend [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24077013/2842227) to add a more complex key to the list sort:

```py3
class SortedListEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj):
        def get_key(item):
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                return get_key(sorted(item.keys()))
            else:
                return str(item)
        def sort_lists(item):
            if isinstance(item, list):
                return sorted((sort_lists(i) for i in item), key=lambda nm: get_key(nm))
            elif isinstance(item, dict):
                return {k: sort_lists(v) for k, v in item.items()}
            else:
                return item
        return super(SortedListEncoder, self).encode(sort_lists(obj))
```

which allows dicts to be compared based on the sorted list of keys.

This is not a complete ordering of the object but it returns the same ordering for both of your test cases (and mine):

```
{"aaa": "aaa", "op": "ccc", "oppa": {"flt": {"nnn": [{"iii": [2, 3, 4, 5]}, {"mmm": [{"a_b_c": [6, 7]}, {"a_b_d": [6]}]}]}, "ggg": [{"fff": "ev"}]}, "rrr": {}, "ttt": ["aaa-bbb-ccc"]}
```

It cant cover the ordering of a list containing dicts that have the same "first" key but different values ie:

```
a=[{"bb": ["aa", "dd"]}, {"bb": ["cc", "dd"]}]
b=[{"bb": ["dd", "cc"]}, {"bb": ["dd", "aa"]}]
```

produces sorted sublists but leaves the dictionary order unaltered:

```
[{"bb": ["aa", "dd"]}, {"bb": ["cc", "dd"]}]
[{"bb": ["cc", "dd"]}, {"bb": ["aa", "dd"]}]
```

Answer (score -1):

I leave this here because i ran into the same issue.

You can use this function to sort your nested data structures:

```py
def sort_data(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        output = OrderedDict()
        for key, value in data.items():
            output[key] = sort_data(value)
        return output
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        calculated = [sort_data(x) for x in data]
        return sorted(calculated, key=str)
    elif isinstance(data, (int, bool, str, float, type(None))):
        return data
    else:
        raise Exception("Unkown type: {} for {}".format(type(data), data))
```

Example:

```py
data = {"b":[ "zzz", "yyy", "xxx"],
        "d": [42, 54, 675, "aaa"],
        "c": {"a": ["bbb", "ccc", "aaa"]},
        }

sorted_data = sort_data(data)
print(json.dumps(sorted_data, indent=2, sort_keys=True))

# prints:
#{
#    "b": [
#        "xxx",
#        "yyy",
#        "zzz"
#    ],
#    "c": {
#        "a": [
#            "aaa",
#            "bbb",
#            "ccc"
#        ]
#    },
#    "d": [
#        42,
#        54,
#        675,
#        "aaa"
#    ]
#}
```