# Order list of Json object by value using python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have this Json object that I created using json dumps:

```
  data.append({"word":word,'list':list , "count":count})

  value=json.dumps({"data":data })

 {"data": [{"count": 1, "word": "bob", "list": [1]}, {"count": 10, "word": "lola", "list": [2,7]}]}
```

I want to order this object according to "count", and have instead this output:

```
 {"data": [{"count": 1O, "word": "lola", "list": [2,7]}, {"count": 1, "word": "bob", "list": [2]}]}
```

Any help on how to order this type of objects? I have already tried this solution: [How to get sorted list inside a dictionary with json.dumps()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076832/how-to-get-sorted-list-inside-a-dictionary-with-json-dumps) from Martijn Pieters, but it orders the list according to 'list' not count.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Simply sort data based on 'count' and then pass it to `json.dumps()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the line

```
value=json.dumps({"data":data })
```

with

```
value = json.dumps({'data': sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['count'], reverse=True)})
```

You should get

```
{"data": [{"count": 10, "list": [2, 7], "word": "lola"}, {"count": 1, "list": [1], "word": "bob"}]}
```